# Fetch Response time in react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using fetch API to fetch data in **react.js**. My API are in **node.js** which is on different server.

One of my API is taking approx 2-3 minutes to fetch data but till the time response is coming from node.js,react.js is throwing unable to fetch data error(response is still coming from node.js but it is coming late so the screens is showing the error,till the time response comes).

I tried with timeout function also but the result is same.This is happening only with the API taking long time to fetch data.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking - how to improve the API response time, or how to handle long response times in fetch?

Comment: How to handle long response time in fetch??

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46946573/1736301