# Removing Fetch API default timeout

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, fetch-api

I'm sending queries to my server using native fetch from Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
  credentials: 'include'
})
```

I set up a server to send a response after 3 minutes and realized that both browsers only wait 2 minutes. Firefox resend the request once more before failing.

Is there a way to define a timeout bigger than 2 minutes (say infinite)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46946380/fetch-api-request-timeout and https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/20#issuecomment-323740783

Comment: I understand @sideshowbarker but all these descriptions show how to reduce the timout. I cannot set 3 minutes timeout by hand if my fetch promise rejects after 2 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I read fetch()'s documentation on MDN, it does not have any way to specify a timeout.

You can use **request** or **axios** module if you are using nodejs.
or you can use **XMLHttpRequest** (plain javascript in browser).

For more information [HTTP request timeouts in JavaScript](https://shuheikagawa.com/blog/2017/05/13/http-request-timeouts-in-javascript/)

Comment: It seems to me XMLHttpRequest timeout works on FireFox you can set it to any value and if you don't the default is it will wait forever. Good, although I would prefer to use fetch(). BUT Chrome seems to always timeout in about 2 minutes no matter what I do .

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to

```
async function fetchJSON(url: string, data: any = {}, method: string = "POST"): Promise<any> {
    const start = new Date().getSeconds();
    const timeoutTimer = 10000
    
    while (new Date().getSeconds() - start < 10) {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(url, {
                method,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            });

            try {
                return await res.json();
            } catch (e) {
                if (res.status < 400) {
                    return res.status;
                } else {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            await new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(resolve, timeoutTimer);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

that is, the timeout is 10 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

To make the timeout "infinite" I use this:

```
fetch (serverUrl)
.then
( resp  => resp.json()
)
.then
( json => $cback (json)
)
.catch
( e    => $cback (e)
);
```

The '$cback' is an in-scope visible callback-function
which detects if it's 1st argument is an instanceof
Error. If so it will make a new call to fetch().
If it does NOT detect it is an error it uses the
response for whatever it was intended, and then 
makes a new call to fetch.

This seems to work great on FireFox. The fetch does
not timeout which is what I want. Unfortunately
on Chrome fetch() ALWAYS times out in about 2 minutes
That causes the catch-clause to fire, in other words
the timeout is seen as an error. But I catch it.

The real problem for me on Chrome is that even 
though I catch the error it still produces an 
error-entry in the log about the no-response-request.
So if users leave their browser open before going 
to lunch they will see many error-messages in their 
browser-log (if they care to look) and I'm afraid 
the number of errors there will cause them to 
"freak out".