# Is it possible that the fetch can throw a network failure error if not received response in time?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, networking, fetch

I have doubt regarding fetch. Is it possible that fetch can throw network failure error if the request isn't received in a limited amount of time?

I am facing an issue where I connected to Raspberry Pi's wifi and send some config using fetch, I got the appropriate response but if I send a request to a custom made jig and connect to it's wifi I get network failure.

All the requests are being made when connected to Raspberry Pi's wifi or Jig's wifi. So naturally it isn't connected to the internet.

I just want some clarification. And if that is the case how can it be resolved?

Edit:

I think the issue is with android because when I ran the same thing on iOS it worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing Fetch API default timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470250/removing-fetch-api-default-timeout)

Comment: No it doesn't. There are just ways where calls will be made continuously. It's just I am getting a slow response on postman as well. And it fails on fetch on my app in react native.

Comment: Because I can't think of anything else, it must be due to the speed of the response