# catch fetch ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, fetch

I must be getting old google searches because I can't find any threads on how to do this if you are using javascript's `fetch` not the old `XMLHttpRequest`

I am trying to test whether or not my VM is online. The rest of the VM is locked down but I left an open endpoint for testing.

I tried using the `status` to check if the server is up but gave me a different error than a response error:

```
fetch("https://rockosmodernserver.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/ ", {
            method: "GET",
            }).then(response => response)
            .then(data => {
                if (data.status == 200){
                    console.log("server is up")
                }
                else{
                 console.log("server is down!!")   
                }
            })
```

It works if the server is up but if the server is down I get:

```
VM739:1 GET https://rockosmodernserver.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

when I tried googling this I got solutions for `XMLHttpRequest` but not for the fetch module.

Comment: Why would you expect a server that's offline to return a status code?

Comment: Use `.catch()` to process errors from a promise.

Comment: @Barmar, Isn't fetch catch unable to catch 4xx or 5xx error? I think fetch will consider 404 as a suceessful call and without access the response, we could only know when there are network/sever not responding error??? (is I am wrong?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You looking for catch block. In the catch block you can fetch the errors. Imn the example below you have access to the error object.

```js
fetch("https://rockosmodernserver.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/ ", {
    method: "GET",
    }).then(response => response)
    .then(data => {
        console.log("server is up")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      console.log("server is down!!")   
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If the server doesn't respond, `fetch` takes it as `connection failure` and handles it in the `catch()` block. The `fetch` only executes `then()` blocks when the connection is successful. If the connection was not successful, the `catch()` block will be executed.

```
fetch('something')
 .then( response => {})
 .catch(error => {
   // handle error here
 })
```

[Checking that fetch was successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

Comment: @Barmar Yes. My Bad. Thanks for pointing it

Answer (score 2):

If a server is not answering, he can not give you a response.
Which means there is no status code.

**Update:**
A fetch() promise will reject with a TypeError when a network error is encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server-side, although this usually means permission issues or similar — a 404 does not constitute a network error, for example. An accurate check for a successful fetch() would include checking that the promise resolved, then checking that the Response.ok property has a value of true. The code would look something like this:

```
  fetch('flowers.jpg')
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not OK');
    }
    return response.blob();
  })
  .then(myBlob => {
    myImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
  });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful

**First edit:**
This solution could be helpful, by using a timeout and track that timeout has happened.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50101022/13111978

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).