# Resolve an Await function if it takes more than x seconds in Javascript / Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, aws-lambda

I have an await function() which waits for an external API. Usually, these APIs take 600ms to return data. But sometimes it's taking around 10 seconds. So how do I write a function so that if it takes more than 1 second, then break that function and resolve anyway (don’t wait for the API)

Here's the main function code which calls the API.

```js
console.log("Before Await");

await fetchExternalAPI("data");

console.log("Continue if success or takes more than x seconds");
```

The actual function:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = async function fetchExternalAPI(data) {

    try {
        const response = await fetch("https://www.example.com/api/log", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });

        const returnData = await response.json();
        console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(returnData))
        return returnData
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Error: " + e)
        return e
    } 
}
```

I want to return success fo the above function

1. if fetch is success
2. or if exceeded more than x seconds

Both should return success no matter the real output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch API request timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46946380/fetch-api-request-timeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AbortController` to `abort` the fetch method, inside a `setTimeout` with 1sec, and if the `fetch` resolved before the `setTimeout` callback execute, then `clearTimeout`

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = async function fetchExternalAPI(data) {

    try {
        let controller = new AbortController();
        let timeId = setTimeout(() => {
           controller.abort()
 
        }, 1000)
        const response = await fetch("https://www.example.com/api/log", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
            signal: controller.signal
        });
        clearTimeout(timeId)
        const returnData = await response.json();
        console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(returnData))
        return returnData
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Error: " + e)
        return e
    } 
}
```

Comment: Does this controller.abort() throws error? Can we silently skip this if it's aborted?

Comment: Yes, it throws an error called `AbortError`, try to catch it with `try/catch` syntax inside the `setTimeout` callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Axios.

```
npm i axios
```

than in body you have one property timeout.

```
const instance = await axios.create({
 baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a promise in your call to resolve on time and reject if too long.
The following code has not been tested but that's the idea

```
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');

  module.exports = async function fetchExternalAPI(data) {

    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://www.example.com/api/log", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      });

      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(reject, 50000));
        resolve();
      }).then(() => {
        const returnData = await response.json();
        console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(returnData))
        return returnData
      }).catch(() => {
        return 'Took too long';
      }));
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log("Error: " + e)
      return e
    } 
  }
```