Don't report a fetch timeout as an uncaught exception
I use:
fetch("/test", { signal: AbortSignal.timeout(2000) })
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => { console.log(r["data"]) });

with the method from Fetch API request timeout? to abort the request after 2 seconds if no response.
In the case of a timeout, I have a JS error in the console:

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation timed out.

What's the simplest way to avoid having this reported as an error?
I would like the timeouts to be silently ignored.
Is this possible with fetch("/test", { signal: AbortSignal.timeout(2000) })? I specifically wanted to use this solution instead of more complex solutions of Fetch API request timeout?.

Have a look at the alternative answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46946380/fetch-api-request-timeout/57888548#57888548

@fdomn-m No, I already mentioned this in my question, did you notice it?

@evolutionxbox fetch("/test", { signal: AbortSignal.timeout(2000) }) works well and is a very handy one-line solution, I just want to remove the error logging. Do I really need a complex solution that removes the benefit of fetch(...).then(...) in one line?

What about adding .catch?

Error is about uncaught promise rejection. Have you tried catching the promise rejection? This may or may not resolve your issue but it is worth a try.

did you try to catch the rejection caused by the abort

@evolutionxbox with .catch(err => {}), there is no more "uncaught exception" mention, so it's better, but the error is still logged in the console. Any idea?

With the code provided and adding .catch(err => {}) no error shows. Please may you update the question?

but the error is still logged - which error? the failed request? yes, that will be logged, of course

@fdomn-m - the link in the question is the link suggested in the comment :p

As mentioned in a comment, the solution is to add
.catch(error => {});

I was doing it wrong before.
