# How to handle Axios timeout with hanging API server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Having issues trying to get `timeout` method of axios working.

For testing: I setup a intentionally bad API endpoint: it accepts a request, throws an error (Eg: `throw new Error(“testing for timeout”)`) and intentionally does nothing else.

My client app (reactJS) hangs once I make a call to the test API endpoint - I expected it to timeout within 2 seconds (my set timeout). I can verify that the app is making contact with server. Its only when I kill my test API server that my client app immediately continues.

Sample code:

```
const axios = require('axios')

const test1Press = async () => {
  try
  {
    await axios.post('https://mynodeserver.com/api/debug/throw', {timeout: 2000})
    console.log("post call passed")
  }
  catch (err)
  {
    console.log("post call failed")
  }
}
```

**EDIT (~2020):**

On further research, looks like axios `timeout` is only for **response** timeouts but not **connection** timeouts. Suggested solutions for **connection** timeouts are [cancellation methods](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation) (e.g. `signal`, `cancelToken (deprecated)`):

Tested this and working:

```
const source = CancelToken.source();
try {
  let response = null;
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (response === null) {
      source.cancel();
    }
  }, 2000);
        
  response = await axios.post('/url',null,{cancelToken: source.token});
  // success
} catch (error) {
  // fail
}
```

Answer (score 28):

With `await axios.post('/debug/throw', {timeout: 2000})`, actually you **send the payload** `{timeout: 2000}` to the server, not set the timeout to 2 seconds. See an example [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#note-commonjs-usage).

I tested with another syntax of axios and it worked

```
const test1Press = async () => {

    console.log("test1 pressed")

    // obviously not the actual url in this stackoverflow post
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:9000'

    console.log("pre call")
    console.log(new Date().toUTCString());
    try {
        await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/',
            timeout: 2000 // only wait for 2s
        })
        console.log(new Date().toUTCString());
        console.log("post call passed")
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(new Date().toUTCString());
        console.log("post call failed")
    }
}

test1Press();
```

On the server-side, I wait for 5 seconds to have the timeout error on the client-side

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        res.write('Hello World!');
        res.end();
    }, 5 * 1 * 1000); // after 5s
})
    .listen(9000);
```

Running the code above gives me the timeout error after 2 seconds

```
test1 pressed
pre call
Mon, 28 Jun 2021 09:01:54 GMT
Mon, 28 Jun 2021 09:01:56 GMT
post call failed
```

---

**EDIT**
I tested to create the instance of axios, this gives me the same result:

```
const test1Press = async () => {

    console.log("test1 pressed")

    // obviously not the actual url in this stackoverflow post
    const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:9000',
        timeout: 2000,
    });

    console.log("pre call")
    console.log(new Date().toUTCString());
    try {
        await instance.post('/');
        console.log(new Date().toUTCString());
        console.log("post call passed")
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(new Date().toUTCString());
        console.log("post call failed")
    }
}

test1Press();
```

Comment: Your second example is the same as my last. I've changed my server code to match yours so it's now "sleeping" instead of throwing an error.. and still my app waits for 5 seconds and I don't get the 2 second failed catch block - with both versions. Hmmm. I don't think then this is a syntax issue; could be related to some sort of conflict with axios/react/other

Comment: I'm using https - ie url of https://myurl.com/api/debug/throw    would https cause an issue with timeout ?

Comment: I don't think it's related to https/http. I didn't test with react, might be it's the difference. Can you do a test with only axios ?

Comment: this is where my limited experience with react/javascript/axios comes into play :( we are committed heavily to a react solution but I could replace axios with another package; I might try that

Comment: This link does suggest that axios works well with react and supports timeouts..https://medium.com/enappd/how-to-make-api-calls-in-react-native-apps-eab083186611

Comment: I think this should work with react. The object is just to isolate the problem :). I admitted that it's weird if we run the same code and the result is different. My axios version is 0.21.1 if it matters

Comment: and this link shows there was issues with timeout in May 2020: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/647 - this may not have been fixed yet; I may need to try the cancel token route

Comment: I appreciate the help you've given - if you want to include the canceltoken code as an alternate in your post I can mark as accepted ?

Comment: You found it, great research :) I don't think it needed because all information is now in your question :)

Answer (score 6):

As indicated in [@arthankamal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54573024/7650275), `timeout` property is only responsible for **response** timeouts but not **connection** timeouts. To address **connection** timeouts, use [axios's cancellation methods](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation). Adding examples below based on newer `signal` property (`cancelToken` is deprecated ).

---

**Example** with `signal` and [AbortSignal.timeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/timeout) built-in [requires nodejs 17.3+]:

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: '/foo/bar',
  timeout: 5000,
  signal: AbortSignal.timeout(5000) //Aborts request after 5 seconds
})
.then(function(response) {
  //...
});
```

**Example** with `signal` and a timeout helper function:

```
function newAbortSignal(timeoutMs) {
  const abortController = new AbortController();
  setTimeout(() => abortController.abort(), timeoutMs || 0);

  return abortController.signal;
}

axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: '/foo/bar',
  timeout: 5000,
  signal: newAbortSignal(5000) //Aborts request after 5 seconds
})
.then(function(response) {
  //...
});
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but note that if you are using Axios in the context of React Native, RN doesn't include an implementation for `AbortSignal.timeout()`

Comment: The helper function looks promising though.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say you've requested the URL through axios and server is taking long time to respond, in this case the axios timeout will work.

> But you don't have internet connection or the IP address or domain name that you're requesting not there, in this case axios timeout will not work.

[See original answer for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54573024/11635043)

Comment: Link is a different issue. I can verify that a connection is made. So internet connection/IP Address/domain name are all ok; i've got the server logging that a request was made. So in this case the axios time out should work, but it's not