# node-fetch and axios GET call hangs forever

Tags: node.js, axios, node-fetch

I have this small node-typescript project that gets a bunch of links from shops like ikea, homedepot and amazon from google sheets, makes `fetch` calls to get some information from a product, and then saves it back into google sheets.

I am running into this problem where most of the `fetch` calls are working just fine. But for some reason, the a few of them (specifically the home depot ones) just hangs forever. Doesn't timeout, doesn't throw an error, just basically hangs indefinitely.

**What I've tried**

- I tried with both `node-fetch` and `axios`, and both are having the same issue.
- I saw [this GH Issue](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1589#issuecomment-1162715462) where the person said it doesn't happen on node-fetch `v2`. I was using `^3.4.4`, so I tried switching so a few v2 versions, but still didn't work.
- Tried adding a few different `User-Agents` and `Accept` into the request header, and still nothing

**My Code**

```
try {
        const productNumber = extractHomeDepotProductNumber(url);
        if (!productNumber) continue;

        const headers = {
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
          'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      }

        const res = await axios.get(
          `https://www.homedepot.ca/api/productsvc/v1/products/${productNumber}/store/7142?fields=BASIC_SPA&lang=en`, {headers}
        );
        console.log('I got res') // this never gets printed
        const resWithImage = await axios.get(
          `https://www.homedepot.ca/api/fbtsvc/v1/fbt/products/${productNumber}/store/7142?checkStockAndPrice=true&lang=en`, {headers}
        );
        console.log('I got resWithImage')
} catch (error) {
        console.log(error) // this never gets printed
}
```

https://github.com/augustoapg/f2-google-sheet/blob/main-node/app/index.ts#L111-L125

**Example of URL with Issues**

- https://www.homedepot.ca/product/kraus-mateosingle-lever-pull-down-kitchen-faucet-chrome/1000860141, which is used to get the product number of `1000860141`, which is then used to make the fetch call to https://www.homedepot.ca/api/productsvc/v1/products/1000860141/store/7142?fields=BASIC_SPA&lang=en, which is the one that gets the fetch stuck

**Fun fact (not sure if relevant)**

I was actually doing this project with Bun, but decided to change to Node for issues with deployment. On Bun, this was working just fine when running locally. When building the project, however, I was having the same error.

Comment: Check this post for axios timeout. Maybe it's the anwser you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690451/timeout-feature-in-the-axios-library-is-not-working

Comment: @GustavoGarcia it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but the timeout part is still quite useful, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by setting the headers of the request to this:

```
const headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
}
```

If I remove any one of these, I get no response.  Note, I'm also using a newer version of Chrome for the user agent (just because that's what my local Chrome agent is), but your version works for me too when combined with these other headers.

And, here's my whole stand-alone test code:

```
import axios from 'axios';


const productNumber = '1000860141';

const headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
}

try {
    const res = await axios.get(
        `https://www.homedepot.ca/api/productsvc/v1/products/${productNumber}/store/7142?fields=BASIC_SPA&lang=en`, 
        { headers, timeout: 2000 }
    );

    console.log(res.data);
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}
```

Comment: That is awesome, it worked! Thank you so much @jfriend00 ! Don't really understand how it was working before when I was using Bun, but great to know how to fix this! Thanks you!

Comment: @AugustoPeres - For issues like this, the target server is looking for certain characteristics of the request to see if it thinks this is a bot or an end-user browser or something else and perhaps only letting things through that smell like a browser.  It wouldn't be surprising that a different environment (e.g. Bun) might present a slightly different looking http request that is somehow (blind luck) more likely to get through.

Comment: that makes sense @jfriend00! I initially suspected it was something like that, but didn't think that Bun might have been sending different requests. That's very good to know, thank you!